# Passkit V2 PHP SDK Authorization always return Invalid Token error

Tags: php, ios, wallet, passkit

I am using [PassKit SDK for PHP](https://github.com/PassKitInc/PHP-SDK) to manage Apple wallet passes. Below is the code which I have written for Authorization.

```
<?php
include_once "PHP-SDK/passkit-v2-sdk.php";

$pk = new PassKit("myApiKey","myApiSecret");

$result = $pk->ListCampaigns();

echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); exit;
```

But It always return below invalid token error for any API.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => Invalid token. Please make sure your token is valid.
)
```

I don't know where I'm doing wrong. My API keys are correct. I simply follow their instructions. I also check [Passkit V2](https://dev.passkit.net/#sdk) document.

Please guide me how can I resolve this error Or Suggest me any better way to create and update with Push notification Apple wallet passes using PHP.

Please help. Thanks in advance!